# Compute Engine With VPC Firewall Open Could Not Connect To Mongo Port 27017 Remotely

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, database-connection, google-compute-engine, firewall

I installed MongoDB v3.6.4 server. I have the following settings in Google Compute Engine:

**Configuration**

In /etc/mongod.conf file:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

security:
  authorization: enabled
```

I also did the following:

- Removed `mongod.lock`
- Created a firewall rule in VPC for both `tcp:27017` and `udp:27017` to be open.

**Connection:**

I can connect locally by:

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/database -u myusername -p
```

But, I can not connect remotely using an IP address or domain by:

```
mongo my.ip.com:27017/database -u myusername -p
mongo <IP ADDRESS>:27017/database -u myusername -p
```

**Error**

It gives me the error:

```
[thread1] Failed to connect to <IP ADDRESS>:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
[thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server my.ip.com:27017, connection attempt failed : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
```

**Other Things I've Tried**

- switched back and forth from different server versions from micro, small, and 1vCPU (thinking it was the processor)
- Changed configurations over and over of the `net` and `security`
- Added a static IP address.
- Checked my other servers with the same setting which worked and copied from it.
- Checked the logs and it does not give me anything after remotely connecting.
- Checked my firewall name, which is `default-mongodb` for `tcp:27017` and `udp:27017`.

None of the settings in this **specific server** seem to work.

**Other Information**

I'm connecting using Mongo client `v3.4.9`

Did I miss to check something? Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... I did not enter the range for the VPC Firewall Rule.

It should be `0.0.0.0/0` instead of just `0.0.0.0`